# Query Returns Null Fields in Production

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, graphql

I am trying to fetch data from mongoDB using graphql and Meteor. Unfortunately it returns null for some fields where there is a value in the database. This is only happening in Production and Staging environments, which are hosted at mongoDB Atlas. The exact same query is returning the value correctly when connected to a local mongoDB instance. This issue persists when we have the same code deployed on a server at Meteor Galaxy. Has anyone experienced something similar? I would really appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)  :)